# Android Type-0 SMS

Tags: android, sms

How can an incomming Type-0 SMS (please note: "Type-0" is ment, not "Class-0") be caught by a BroadcastReceiver?

Background: For configuration purposes Type-0 SMS (with TP-PID=ME data download) are sent. This needs to be "intercepted" by an Android application and the data inside the message needs to be retrieved/ decoded.

So the intention is to READ Type-0 SMS, NOT sending it!

Is it possible with Android at all? Is perhaps a native app necessary?

Thanks and kind regards!

Answer (score 1):

Consider looking into this project as they have accomplished this:

https://github.com/SecUpwN/Android-IMSI-Catcher-Detector

Answer (score 0):

You can do it natively in Android. About 10 years ago, Google made silent sms really silent. So, just reverse that commit. [Android Commit to silence type zero sms](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/14069/)

In later versions of android, the corresponding files have been moved to /frameworks/opt/telephony/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/gsm. They are SmsMessage.java and GsmInboundSmsHandler.java